# Proving that cycle is unstable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving a few problems of Arnold - Ordinary Differential Equations, and i have a problem with the problem 1 page 51 nd says:

> Prove that if $ \lambda>1$, then the cycle is unstable and the phase curves originating near a cycle are unwinding spirals diverging from the cycle; if $ \lambda<1$ then the cycle is stable and the phase curves originating in a neighborhood of it are spirals winding onto the cycle

and i have a hint

> Consider the return function $ \Phi$  defined by the solutions $ \phi$ of Eq. (2) 
>   (this is $ \frac{dY}{dX}=a(X,Y), a(X,0)=0, a(X+T,Y)=a(X,Y)$) and assigning to the initial condition $Y=\phi(0)$ for $X=0$ the value $ \Phi(Y)=\phi(T)$. Prove that the linearization  of $\Phi$ at the point $Y=0$ is a monodromy operator

I don't understand the hint. does this mean that if $\phi$ is a solution of Eq. (2) with initial condition $r=\phi(0)$ then i construct the return function $ \Phi$ =  $ \Phi(r)=\phi(T)$? How can I prove that the linearisation of $\Phi$ is a monodromy operator (for the initial equation?) How is this related to $\lambda$ and to the stability of the cycle for the generic non linear case?

Any advice will be thankful. P.S. (i'm sorry for my bad english)